FME: Split Lines on Points and assign point values to line sections
I have a question about the correct combination of FME transformers, NeighborFinder, PointOnLineOverlayer and ListExploder:
I have points (river levels) and lines (rivers). The points should intersect the lines at the overlap. That works so far.
A river can have several level measurement points. The river sections are to be assigned the attributes of the “correct” gauges.
Example: River 1 consists of 4 sections (created with PointOnLineOverlayer+ListExploder). However, each section is now assigned the values of all gauges, i.e. each feature exists 4 times with all measured values. Now, however, section 1 of the river from the spring to level/gauge station 1 should receive the measured values of level 1, section 2 of the river the measured values of level 2, etc. up to the last level point. The section after the last gauge point should always receive the values of the previous point, so to speak.
The result should therefore be a line (river) with id, which is divided into its sections and each section (with river id + level id) is assigned the measured level values.
Any ideas?

Are you wanting this in QGIS or FME Form (desktop)?

Best solution would be by FME, but if not possible also in QGIS

I think such questions are best accompanied with a diagram of what you want to achieve as its not immediately clear what you want. Edit your question and insert an sketch of what you have and what you want to achieve.

are the points (gauges) in good sequence in your database/file? Meaning ordered in the same direction? Station1 then station 2 then station 3 ....?
